# Par() function in R,plot not shown

Tags: r, statistics

Hey there stackoverflow geeks, I am working with a dataset in R language using R studio. I want to display my pareto charts *side by side* so better analysis can be done.

When I use **par()** function , i only get the first plot with an empty white space on right, can anyone please help me with what the issue is?

```
library(qcc)

stateRegion <- table(state.region)
stateDivision <- table(state.division)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))   

pareto.chart(stateRegion)          #only this one appears
pareto.chart(stateDivision)        #this one is not plotting
```

**EDIT**
The code is working with all other plots except pareto chart/plot.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809127/r-plotting-multiple-qcccusum-charts-in-one-display

Comment: I have posted a question relating to this to [R-Help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2022-April/474269.html) and already got an answer that seems useful. So the first impression is that's not a bug but that the package maintainer should follow this question and that thread.